# Google Analytics is displaying different data when accessed from different devices

Tags: google-analytics

I was recently checking my Google Analytics account. I noticed that it was showing different data for the same property from different laptops. Below are attached screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Can you tell me what could be wrong? I can't show incorrect data to my client.

Comment: I just tried from 2 separate devices and had no issue. Make sure you've refreshed both pages and the URL and account are the same.

Answer (score 2):

The data must be the same regardless the device you are using. If you check the screenshots you will verify that the difference occurs the last day.

That could happen due to a report cache and [data processing latency](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en#DataProcessingLatency)

> Processing latency is 24-48 hours. Standard accounts that send more
>   than 200,000 sessions per day to Analytics will result in the reports
>   being refreshed only once a day. This can delay updates to reports and
>   metrics for up to two days. To restore intra-day processing, reduce
>   the number of sessions your account sends to < 200,000 per day.